# SonarQube false-positive "unused private methods should be removed" in static method

Tags: java, sonarqube

Example code:

```
public static String foo(){
 return bar();
}

private static String bar(){
 return "";
}
```

SonarQube marks bar() function as unused, but SonarLint (IntelliJ, version 2.7.1.1640) works fine.
I have installed latest version of SonarQube (6.2) and latest version of Java plugin (4.5.0.8398), but still have this issue - i thought this issue was fixed?
Is this some kind of regression bug?
Thanks for your help.

UPDATE:

Above example was too trivial, i manage to specify problem: it looks like a problem with primitive arguments passed to function, for example this is marked as unused:

```
public static String foo( SomeClass a ) {
    return bar( a.getChar() );
  }

  private static String bar( char a ) {
    return String.valueOf( a );
  }
```

if i pass hardcoded value to bar (like bar('a') ) everything works fine (or even when i pass something like bar("string".charAt(0) ) ). SomeClass.getChar() return 'char' so it is not a problem with boxing primitives.

SOLUTION:
as @Michael - SonarSource Team suggested, there was a problem with dependencies bytecodes. I disabled teamcity Sonar runner plugin and now run sonarqube via Gradle plugin.

Comment: How about asking this on somekind of support forum or bug tracker on SonarQube?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with same configuration. Are you sure you are providing the bytecode of your files when performing the analysis for SonarQube?

Comment: John - you're right, i should and probably i will send this as a bug to SonarQube, but i wanted to be sure it's not my mistake.
@Michael-SonarSourceTeam - please look at my update.

Comment: @szymonszymon it seems to me that the analyzer don't have access to 'SomeClass' bytecode, and therefore can't resolve the return type of the method invocation. Can't be simple boxing issue if the method returns a 'char' as well. SonarLint should provide dependencies correctly while the SonarQube scan is not. How do you perform the SonarQube analysis?

Comment: @Michael-SonarSourceTeam I perform the SonarQube analysis through Sonar runner plugin in Teamcity (version 116) as one of my build steps.

Answer (score -2):

Many times there are some problem with sync of sonar server and sonar lint ,it is not with this single issue , it is also replicated in other issues as well like duplicate code.refer sonar server and try to solve

Comment: What do you mean by "refer sonar server and try to solve"!? to me it seems more like a configuration error of the SonarQube analysis, while SonarLint is performing well on its own.